# Generating same ID for every 11 observations

Tags: stata

I am reshaping data from the SESTAT data explorer tool. I am trying to generate the same id number for every 11 observations. I have attempted coding it using `gen` and `egen` and it is not working. Any suggestions of how I can improve my code?

`````
gen id = _n + 10 ````
`````

I also tried

`gen id = [n+10]`

`egen id = A[n+10]`

Comment: The first is legal and yields 11, 12, and so on. The second is legal if there is a numeric variable or scalar `n`. The third is always illegal, as `egen` requires one of its own functions to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
     egen id = seq(), block(11)
```